# Errors while installing dependencies for pyCGNS

Tags: python, cgns

I've a bunch of dependencies that have to be installed before trying to install [pyCGNS](http://pycgns.sourceforge.net/). So I've probably did something wrong on the road, can someone tell me what ?

Actually the [required dependencies](http://pycgns.sourceforge.net/install.html#required-libraries) are:

> Python (starting from v2.4)
>   numpy (v1.1 +)
>   cython (v0.16 +)
>   VTK (v5.8 +)
>   Qt (v4.7 +)
>   pySide (for Qt v4.7 +)
>   hdf5 (v1.8.5 +)

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.6

$ python -c 'import numpy;print numpy.version.version'
1.9.2

$ cython --version
Cython version 0.22

$ python -c 'import vtk; print vtk.VTK_VERSION'
5.8.0

$ pkg-config --modversion QtCore
4.8.6

$ python -c 'import PySide; print PySide.__version__'
1.2.2
```

The [`CHLone` documentation](http://chlone.sourceforge.net/install.html#hdf5-requirements) says that I must have the *thread-safe* feature of `HDF5` enabled to be able to install CHLone.

> The CHLone requires you have the thread-safe feature of HDF5 enabled.
>   You have setup the HDF5 build with the thread-safe and the
>   enable-pthreads flags in the configure command line...

So I did this to install `HDF5`:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/hdf5 --libdir=/usr/local/hdf5/lib --bindir=/usr/local/hdf5/bin --enable-shared --with-pic
$ make
$ make install
```

> CHLone (v0.4 +)

To install CHLone, I used `scons` like indicated in [the documentation](http://chlone.sourceforge.net/install.html#build-and-install):

```
scons
scons install root=/usr/local
```

### Installing pyCGNS

I've edited the `pyCGNSconfig_user.py` to indicate hdf5 and CHLone locations:

```
HDF5_PATH_INCLUDES    = ['/usr/local/hdf5/include']
HDF5_PATH_LIBRARIES   = ['/usr/local/hdf5/lib']
CHLONE_PATH_INCLUDES    = ['/usr/local/include/CHLone']
CHLONE_PATH_LIBRARIES   = ['/usr/local/lib']
```

Then I used these commandes to install it:

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install --prefix=/usr/local
```

Now when I run [tests in the documentation](http://pycgns.sourceforge.net/install.html#test) it outputs:

```
$ python -c 'import CGNS.MAP.test;CGNS.MAP.test.run()'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named CGNS.MAP.test
```

Comment: Can someone [help me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40827367/chlone-installation-fails) with installing CHLone?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of **pyCGNS** do you use?

Did you test a simple import using `python -c 'import CGNS.MAP'`?

Maybe the **CHLone** lib is not in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which makes the import fail.

Comment: pyCGNS v4.4. The simple import does not work. I tried to add CHLone lib to LD_LIBRARY_PATH but still doesn't work.

Comment: You should have a `libCHLone.so` in `/usr/local/lib` and a `CHLone.so` in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, some installations may duplicate the lib so that you would also find  a `/usr/local/lib64` for both the shared lib and the python module. Then if your env variables are set this should succeed: `python -c 'import CHLone'`