# CHLone installation fails

Tags: hdf5, scons

I am trying to install [CHLone](http://chlone.sourceforge.net) v0.49 on Ubuntu 16.04 in order to install [pyCGNS](http://pycgns.sourceforge.net/). The dependencies are installed and seem to be found by scons, as the beginning of the output shows when I run `scons`:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
# =================================================================
# CHLone: production setup...
# CHLone: Cython & numpy found, add CGNS/Python build
# CHLone: Configuration uses HDF5 version 1.10.0-patch1 with:
# CHLone: + thread safe HDF5
# CHLone: + includes in ['/usr/local/hdf5/include']
# CHLone: + libraries in ['/usr/local/hdf5/lib']
# CHLone: compiler is gcc
# =================================================================
# CHLone: Build v0.49
# =================================================================
scons: done reading SConscript files.
```

However, it then runs into problems with an output like:

```
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
# CHLone: Compiling shared src/l3.c
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/l3.c: In function 'objlist_status':
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/l3.c:172:14: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'hid_t {aka long int}' [-Wformat=]
       printf("# L3 :HDF5 ID %d ALIVE (%s:%d) {%s}\n", \
              ^
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/l3.c: In function 'HDF_Read_Array':
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/l3.c:680:20: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 5 has type 'hsize_t {aka long long unsigned int}' [-Wformat=]
       sprintf(dims,"%s%c%d",dims,pad,int_dim_vals[n]);
                    ^
In file included from .scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/l3P.h:6:0,
                 from .scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/l3.c:42:
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/l3.c:687:19: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 3 has type 'hid_t {aka long int}' [-Wformat=]
     L3M_DBG(ctxt,("HDF_Read_Array ALLOCATE %p from %d size %s)x%d=%d %s\n",
                   ^
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/include/CHLone/l3.h:777:28: note: in definition of macro 'L3M_DBG'
 {printf("# L3 : +");printf msg;fflush(stdout);}}
                            ^
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/l3.c:687:19: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 5 has type 'size_t {aka long unsigned int}' [-Wformat=]
     L3M_DBG(ctxt,("HDF_Read_Array ALLOCATE %p from %d size %s)x%d=%d %s\n",
                   ^
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/include/CHLone/l3.h:777:28: note: in definition of macro 'L3M_DBG'
 {printf("# L3 : +");printf msg;fflush(stdout);}}
                            ^
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/l3.c:687:19: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 6 has type 'long long unsigned int' [-Wformat=]
     L3M_DBG(ctxt,("HDF_Read_Array ALLOCATE %p from %d size %s)x%d=%d %s\n",
                   ^
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/include/CHLone/l3.h:777:28: note: in definition of macro 'L3M_DBG'
 {printf("# L3 : +");printf msg;fflush(stdout);}}
                            ^
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/l3.c:692:19: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 3 has type 'hid_t {aka long int}' [-Wformat=]
     L3M_DBG(ctxt,("HDF_Read_Array NO ALLOCATE %p from %d\n",data,nid));
                   ^
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/include/CHLone/l3.h:777:28: note: in definition of macro 'L3M_DBG'
 {printf("# L3 : +");printf msg;fflush(stdout);}}
                            ^
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/l3.c: In function 'HDF_Get_DataArray':
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/l3.c:779:17: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'hid_t {aka long int}' [-Wformat=]
   L3M_DBG(ctxt,("HDF_Get_DataArray from %d/%d/%d/%d\n",
                 ^
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/include/CHLone/l3.h:777:28: note: in definition of macro 'L3M_DBG'
 {printf("# L3 : +");printf msg;fflush(stdout);}}
                            ^
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/l3.c:779:17: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 3 has type 'hid_t {aka long int}' [-Wformat=]
   L3M_DBG(ctxt,("HDF_Get_DataArray from %d/%d/%d/%d\n",
                 ^
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/include/CHLone/l3.h:777:28: note: in definition of macro 'L3M_DBG'
 {printf("# L3 : +");printf msg;fflush(stdout);}}
                            ^
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/l3.c:779:17: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 4 has type 'hid_t {aka long int}' [-Wformat=]
   L3M_DBG(ctxt,("HDF_Get_DataArray from %d/%d/%d/%d\n",
                 ^
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/include/CHLone/l3.h:777:28: note: in definition of macro 'L3M_DBG'
 {printf("# L3 : +");printf msg;fflush(stdout);}}
                            ^
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/l3.c:779:17: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 5 has type 'hid_t {aka long int}' [-Wformat=]
   L3M_DBG(ctxt,("HDF_Get_DataArray from %d/%d/%d/%d\n",
                 ^
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/include/CHLone/l3.h:777:28: note: in definition of macro 'L3M_DBG'
 {printf("# L3 : +");printf msg;fflush(stdout);}}
                            ^
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/l3.c: In function 'L3_nodeUpdate':
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/l3.c:1318:21: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'hid_t {aka long int}' [-Wformat=]
     L3M_TRACE(ctxt,("L3_nodeUpdate H5Lmove [%d:%s]%d:%s\n",pid,oldname,pid,node->name));
                     ^
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/include/CHLone/l3.h:781:26: note: in definition of macro 'L3M_TRACE'
 {printf("# L3 :");printf msg ;fflush(stdout);}}
                          ^
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/l3.c:1318:21: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 4 has type 'hid_t {aka long int}' [-Wformat=]
     L3M_TRACE(ctxt,("L3_nodeUpdate H5Lmove [%d:%s]%d:%s\n",pid,oldname,pid,node->name));
                     ^
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/include/CHLone/l3.h:781:26: note: in definition of macro 'L3M_TRACE'
 {printf("# L3 :");printf msg ;fflush(stdout);}}
                          ^
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/l3.c: In function 'L3_nodeRetrieve':
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/l3.c:1604:19: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'hid_t {aka long int}' [-Wformat=]
   L3M_TRACE(ctxt,("L3_nodeRetrieve [%d]\n",oid));
                   ^
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/include/CHLone/l3.h:781:26: note: in definition of macro 'L3M_TRACE'
 {printf("# L3 :");printf msg ;fflush(stdout);}}
                          ^
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/l3.c: At top level:
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/l3.c:2045:7: error: conflicting types for 'L3_incRef'
 hid_t L3_incRef(L3_Cursor_t *ctxt,hid_t id)
       ^
In file included from .scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/l3P.h:6:0,
                 from .scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/l3.c:42:
.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/include/CHLone/l3.h:517:10: note: previous declaration of 'L3_incRef' was here
 /*#*/int L3_incRef(L3_Cursor_t *ctxt,hid_t id);
          ^
scons: *** [.scons.linux2.tmp/build/src/l3.os] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Can anyone help me what to do? I have no clue what the problem might be...

Comment: Looks like you're using a newer version of GCC than the code is compilable by.  Note I see only two warnings compiling l3.c, is there more output before the build fails?

Comment: Thanks for help! I updated the post. You can see the complete output now.

Comment: see the line that includes " error:", that's the problem.  Can you check with the project itself to see if someone can fix this? Which version of gcc are you using?  Looks like L3_incRef is being declared in the .h file returning int, and in the c file it returns hid_t...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the answer is in fact in the compiler log. It says that the return type of function `L3_incRef` in `l3.c` (`int`) is not consistent with the one in the header `l3.h` (`hid_t`).

After changing the return type of `L3_incRef` into `int` in `l3.C`, the code compiles successfully.

Comment: EDIT : that is actually what @bdbaddog said five years ago...